# Waiting for forEach loop in aws lambda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, async-await

How can I wait for the forEach loop to finish before the return statement is executed in aws lambda?

```
module.exports.shipments = async (event) => {
    const axios = require("axios");
    let data = JSON.parse(event.body);
    let url = data.apiURL + "/api/1.1/wf/bulkshipments/initialize";
    let patchURL = data.apiURL + "/api/1.1/obj/company/" + data.companyID;

    data.shipments.forEach((item, index, array) => {
        axios.post(url,{
        batchID: data.batchID,
        companyID: data.companyID,
        shipment: item})
    });

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'Created successfully!',
        totalShipments: data.shipments.length,
      }, null, 2),
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already using async, so use map to return a list of promises, and await them all with [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
module.exports.shipments = async (event) => {
    const axios = require("axios");
    let data = JSON.parse(event.body);
    let url = data.apiURL + "/api/1.1/wf/bulkshipments/initialize";
    let patchURL = data.apiURL + "/api/1.1/obj/company/" + data.companyID;
    
    let promises = data.shipments.map(item =>
        axios.post(url, {
            batchID: data.batchID,
            companyID: data.companyID,
            shipment: item})
        })
    );

    await Promise.all(promises);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'Created successfully!',
        totalShipments: data.shipments.length,
      }, null, 2),
    };
};
```

To have each call wait, instead of firing all the post requests at the same time, use a [for...of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```
module.exports.shipments = async (event) => {
    const axios = require("axios");
    let data = JSON.parse(event.body);
    let url = data.apiURL + "/api/1.1/wf/bulkshipments/initialize";
    let patchURL = data.apiURL + "/api/1.1/obj/company/" + data.companyID;

    for (let item of data.shipments) {
        await axios.post(url, {
            batchID: data.batchID,
            companyID: data.companyID,
            shipment: item})
        });
    }

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'Created successfully!',
        totalShipments: data.shipments.length,
      }, null, 2),
    };
};
```

Comment: How can I add a delay between each call?